# Is there way to get data model in onError branch?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java2

I'm getting data model from API through Retrofit and RXJava. Model contains error string with custom message.

`{"data":[],"errors":[{"code":168,"message":"Number is out of bounds"}]}`

Subscribe function:

```
subscribe({
       eventLiveData.value = SubmitFinished
    }, { // it: Throwable!
       eventLiveData.value = SubmitResponseError
       // I want to have my object here!
    })
```

Is there any way to have my object with error code in onError branch?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `onError` you get `Throwable` object and you can cast it to `HttpException`

```
data class Data(
    @SerializedName("content") val content: String
)

data class Error(
    @SerializedName("code") val code: Int,
    @SerializedName("message") val message: String,
)

data class Response(
    @SerializedName("data") val data: List<Data>,
    @SerializedName("errors") val errors: List<Error>
)

fun onError(e: Throwable): List<Error>? {
    return try {
        val httpException = e as? HttpException
        val errors = JSONObject(httpException?.response()?.errorBody()?.string()).get("errors") as List<Error>
    } catch (ignore: Exception) {
        null
    }
}
```

Check this article:

https://medium.com/mindorks/rxjava2-and-retrofit2-error-handling-on-a-single-place-8daf720d42d6

Comment: Posting the actual part relating to the question instead of a link would be much more fitting.